# How to Show Container View's Viewcontroller(child Viewcontroller ) on button click on ParentViewcontroller

Tags: ios

I had embedded a `childViewController` inside my `parent viewcontroller(MainViewController)`..but the problem is that it is already being seen on My `ParentViewcontroller` On background but I Want It on button click.
Can anyone tell me how to show `childviewcontroller` only on Button click..?

Comment: initially hide childViewController's view, on Button click just set hidden false.

Comment: Thanks venkat,but it is restricting my parent viewcontroller subviews also ...why my container views hieght is smaller ,I had not put it on any subviews

Comment: Is there any special reason that you are not using 2 View Controller and calling Push/present method on button click to display second view controller?

Comment: Yeaaa,Its kind of notification wich will come on button ,I'm doing already a lots of stuff on parentviewcontroller

Comment: Not getting you.. What notification? And why its issue?

Comment: I'm using the viewcontroller as a type of notification for user to show on parentveiwcontroller its not a nsnotification

Comment: I'm getting this error   ""There are unexpected subviews in the container view. Perhaps the embed segue has already fired once or a subview was added programmatically?""'

Answer (score 1):

Just hide the ChildViewController's View by using `childView.Hidden = YES` in MainViewController `viewDidLoad`

Then,Show the ChildViewController's View by using `childView.Hidden = NO` in Button Action.

As a Newbie to iOS,I am not sure about this.May be It will be Useful for You.Please upvote if it helps...

Answer (score 0):

Use can use subviews by two ways.

1. Using UIView inside View controller and setting its width and height appropriate to the app's need and you can switch it between hide and unhide.
2. If you want to show some data, that requires reloading, then use UITableView instead of UIView and reload it using "[UITableView reloadData]"